# Retrieving campaign data from Gupshup using API

Tags: python, gupshup

Is it possible to get the Campaign data from Gupshup using their API after someone runs the campaign.
The data should consist of link tracking report and response file

Now we are manually downloading the data from the gupshup platform at the end of the day